# pip cannot confirm SSL certificate: SSL module is not available

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pip

I am trying to install RPi.GPIO for Python 3.6 on my Raspberry Pi Zero W, but somehow it won't connect to the python.org website. I have pip installed for 2.7, 3.0, and 3.6 installed, so when I go and do something like:

```
sudo pip3.6 install RPi.GPIO
```

I get this error:

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3.6 install RPi.GPIO
>   pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
>   Collecting RPi.GPIO
>     Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpi-gpio/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement RPi.GPIO (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for RPi.GPIO

I did try `sudo apt-get install openssl` and so on, but it still doesn't work. I can access the website perfectly on my desktop and phone, but my Raspberry Pi won't at all. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: can you try `http_proxy="" && pip3.6 install RPi.GPIO`

Comment: @HaifengZhang Same issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Before** installing python 3.6 you need to install the libraries needed.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall 
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

Do you have these installed on the PI?

More details [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-6-ubuntu-linuxmint/#)

Comment: Yeah I do have them installed: http://i.imgur.com/mvkDqQe.png - If they got installed before or after I installed Python 3.6... that's unknown.

Comment: The  order is important here. Can you uninstall python and reinstall?

Comment: I suppose, but is that wise?

Comment: As long as you are not running anything that depends on python being installed while you are uninstalling you should be fine.

Comment: The issue isn't really Python here, though? The issue is pip. pip tries to make the connection. I did run `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3` and that didn't really help.

Comment: Maaaybe that's because `python3` is Python 3.4 and not 3.6. Hmm.

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: Like anyone would: wget, tar, configure, make, make install. Compile from source. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/59391/30794

Comment: Hmm. And the packages were installed before you installed from source?

Comment: Currently still reinstalling. This Raspberry Pi Zero W isn't that fast haha. Almost done with `sudo make install`, let's see if that solves it.

Comment: 5 seconds after commenting, it finished and worked! Thanks a lot, I never realised I had to reinstall it completely!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!

Comment: @MortenMoulder How did you uninstall python3.6? I have also gone through the whole process of compiling and installing but I don't know how to reverse this.

Comment: @uitty400 I'm sure you can search and find a way to do that :-)

Answer (score 9):

I encounter the same problem，finally I solved it by following

1. Check whether the openssl-devel has been installed.
   My OS is centos6 and the installing command is as following

   yum install openssl-devel -y
2. Edit python source configure file

   vi /{yourpythonsource}/Modules/Setup

. Uncomment some of content as following

```
# Socket module helper for socket(2)
_socket socketmodule.c timemodule.c



# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other 
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable: 
#SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
-DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
-L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

recompile python.

```
cd /{yourpythonsource}
make && make install
```

Now pip3 should be ok.