# Virtualenv pip ssl - Fails while trying to install any package. ERROR: "ssl module in Python is not available"

Tags: python, ssl, pip, virtualenv

I'm new to virtualenv, and was trying to get it working, in order to work with a given project. I've followed [this](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215317948-How-to-install-Django-using-virtualenv) guide to set it all up. As soon as I get in the virtualenv, pip stops working with the mentioned error.

The exact issue here being this:

```
(virtual-env) $ pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org Django==1.11.4
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting Django==1.11.4
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==1.11.4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Django==1.11.4
```

...yes... `--trusted-host` makes no difference... it seems, because it needs some package I cannot find.

Versions:

- Python

  ```
  $ python --version
  Python 3.6.2
  ```
- Pip

  ```
  $ pip --version # <- Edited
  pip 9.0.1
  ```

I did try to install the ssl module, but to no avail. Turns out you cannot install ssl with python 3. The problem is the print sintax.

```
  [...]
  File "/tmp/pip-build-undfmh27/ssl/setup.py", line 33
    print 'looking for', f
                      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: A few notes. You show us `pip3 --version` but run `pip install`; `pip` (not `pip3`) is supposed to be Python 2.7. The error about missing parentheses in `print` is again Py2 vs Py3: in python 3 `print` is a function `print()`. The module `ssl` at PyPI is [Py2 only](https://github.com/pypa/ssl/issues/7); for Py3 you don't need to install anything — everything is in Python already.

Comment: You are almost right. The thing is, within the virtualenv, pip is nothing but a symbolic link to pip3. I've edited the question to clarify. Thank you!

Comment: Answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822740/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python3-6-on-ubuntu-16-04) question help me with similar to your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... turns out that ther **is** a certain order for installing stuff with python 3.6. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290926/pip-cannot-confirm-ssl-certificate-ssl-module-is-not-available) was very helpful.

Following [this](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-6-ubuntu-linuxmint/#) instructions I was able to make my virtualenv work as I expected.

To sum up.
**Before** installing python 3.6.2 as in the question, you need to prepare the environment as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

And only then, install python 3, and use it within the virtualenv.