# How to use virtualenv with python3.6 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-3.6, virtual-environment

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, which comes with Python 2.7 and Python 3.5. I've installed Python 3.6 on it and symlink python3 to python3.6 through `alias python3=python3.6`.

Then, I've installed `virtualenv` using `sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv`. When I checked, the virtualenv got installed in `"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages"` location, so when I'm trying to create virtualenv using `python3 -m venv ./venv1` it's throwing me errors:

```
Error Command: ['/home/wgetdj/WorkPlace/Programming/Python/myvenv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `update-alternatives`?

Comment: @AhmedNourEideen I rejected your [proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28733675); please don't add `code` formatting to `things which are not code`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

We usually use `$ python3 -m venv myvenv` to create a new virtualenv (Here `myvenv` is the name of our virtualenv).

Similar to my case, if you have both `python3.5` as well as `python3.6` on your system, then you might get some errors.

**NOTE:** On some versions of Debian/Ubuntu you may receive the following error:

```
 The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensure pip is not available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv package using the following command.
      apt-get installpython3-venv  
 You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv package, recreate your virtual environment.
```

In this case, follow the instructions above and install the python3-venv package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

**NOTE:** On some versions of Debian/Ubuntu initiating the virtual environment like this currently gives the following error:

```
Error Command: ['/home/wgetdj/WorkPlace/Programming/Python/myvenv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

To get around this, use the virtualenv command instead.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
$ virtualenv --python=python3.6 myvenv
```

**NOTE:** If you get an error like

> E: Unable to locate package python3-venv

then instead run:

```
sudo apt install python3.6-venv
```

Comment: Very thorough answer but even more errors result from 'sudo apt install python3.6-venv' so I got lazy and went with Orny's answer which seemed to work.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package python3.6-venv
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6-venv'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6-venv'

Answer (score 22):

Installing `python3.6` and `python3.6-venv` via `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` instead of `ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6` worked for me

```
apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y software-properties-common curl \
&& add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y python3.6 python3.6-venv
```

Comment: This worked for me. Seems like some error was introduced recently in the jonathonf repository. I needed to downgrade to standard packages first, see https://askubuntu.com/a/899668/320633.

Answer (score 20):

**Ubuntu**

First make sure you have python3.6 installed, otherwise you can install it with command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt install python3.6
```

Now install venv i.e

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-venv python3.6-dev
python3.6 -m venv venv_name
```

You can install python3.7/3.8 and also respective venv with above comman, just replace 3.6 with 3.X

**For Mac users**
`python3 -m venv venv_name`

Comment: Works as charm on my Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 2):

I think that a problem could be related to the wrong locale.
I added to the `/etc/environment` the following lines to fix it:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

You need to source the file from you bash with this command:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Comment: Nothing works for me. I have tried every solution but none has worked. What version of Ubuntu has the bug been solved, so that I simply install it and uninstall what I have?

Answer (score 1):

if you get following irritating error:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3-venv
```

try this commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

those worked for me.hope it helps !