# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt when creating virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.6

In MACOS `terminal`, when I do `python3 -V`, I get this:

```
Python 3.7.6
```

now I create a `virtualenv` by doing this:

```
dev$ python3 -m venv project-one
```

and `activate` by doing this:

```
dev$ source project-one/bin/activate
```

I have a `requirement.txt` file with the following:

```
python==3.6.8
numpy==1.18.1
matplotlib==3.1.1
```

now I do `pip3 install requirement.txt`

but I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt
```

I used several `python3.6.x` version but it does not work.

**What do I want?**

I want to have a `virtualenv` with `Python` version `python3.6.x` so when I run any code inside the `virtualenv`, it is via `python3.6.x`

Comment: I would recommend checking out [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for Python version control, and [`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) to manage virtual environments with different Python versions. Should be straight forward to install both: `brew install pyenv` ([brew.sh](https://brew.sh))

Comment: You omitted the `-r` flag that denotes you are using a requirements file.  `pip3 install -r requirement.txt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use virtualenv with python3.6 on ubuntu 16.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822740/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python3-6-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
virtualenv -ppython3 .venv
```

That will create virtualenv with python 3. You can also be more specific:

```
virtualenv -ppython36 .venv
```

if you have it installed.

Comment: RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python36'

Answer (score 0):

Do this, it needs root permission to fetch pythonx from the internet if it's not locally installed.

```
sudo apt install python3.6-venv
```