# pip3 can't install anything due to some reason about ssl

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, openssl, pip

After upgrading my ubuntu server 16.04, I can't install modules with pip3 for my python3.6. This is what I get when I try to install tensorflow-gpu for python3:

```
root@amax:~# pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/tensorflow-gpu/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu
```

This is my python3 and pip3 version:

```
root@amax:~# python3 -V
Python 3.6.1
root@amax:~# which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
root@amax:~# pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

I am sure that the openssl is installed on my server:

```
root@amax:~# apt -y install openssl libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu13).
openssl is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu13).
```

I think the cause of the problem might be the version of my pip3 doesn't match the openssl version. What should I do? Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip cannot confirm SSL certificate: SSL module is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290926/pip-cannot-confirm-ssl-certificate-ssl-module-is-not-available)

Comment: I've tried all the solutions in the page, which doesn't help.

Comment: You have to reinstall python after installing SSL libraries because Python's ssl module will be (or not) installed depending on the libraries' existance. Verify Python's ssl module with `python -c "import ssl"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you can download a `.whl` file and install it with pip3

The wheel file can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow)

and then just use this to install

```
pip3 install /home/Downloads/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

Hopes this solves your problem

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am sure it will help, but I've been using wget and pip3 for half  an hour to deal with the dependency problem. I've installed bleach, enum34, numpy, protobuf, six, Werkzeug, wheel and so on manually, but the tensorflow-gpu still needs extra packages. And I don't know whether I can finish the process within 2 more hours since the tensorflow-gpu depends on too many packages. So is there a way which helps to deal with the process more conveniently? Thanks!

Comment: What system are you running on Windows or Linux?

Comment: My server is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Well check this website out and try and install it from scratch [here](https://alliseesolutions.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/install-gpu-tensorflow-from-sources-w-ubuntu-16-04-and-cuda-8-0/)

Comment: Just change the version numbers as per your requirement. I had setup scripts which I made to help a friend but I couldnt find it at the moment,