# ImportError: cannot import name 'KO_NAMES' from 'charset_normalizer.constant'

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I was trying to use RandAugment supported by torchvision, but encountered this Error

input:

```
from torchvision.transforms import v2
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/compat.py:11
     10 try:
---> 11     import chardet
     12 except ImportError:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 1
----> 1 import torchvision

File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py:6
      3 from modulefinder import Module
      5 import torch
----> 6 from torchvision import datasets, io, models, ops, transforms, utils
      8 from .extension import _HAS_OPS
     10 try:

File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/__init__.py:1
----> 1 from ._optical_flow import FlyingChairs, FlyingThings3D, HD1K, KittiFlow, Sintel
      2 from ._stereo_matching import (
      3     CarlaStereo,
      4     CREStereo,
   (...)
     12     SintelStereo,
     13 )
     14 from .caltech import Caltech101, Caltech256

File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/_optical_flow.py:13
     10 from PIL import Image
     12 from ..io.image import _read_png_16
---> 13 from .utils import _read_pfm, verify_str_arg
     14 from .vision import VisionDataset
     17 T1 = Tuple[Image.Image, Image.Image, Optional[np.ndarray], Optional[np.ndarray]]

File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/utils.py:22
     19 from urllib.parse import urlparse
     21 import numpy as np
---> 22 import requests
     23 import torch
     24 from torch.utils.model_zoo import tqdm

File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:45
     41 import warnings
     43 import urllib3
---> 45 from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
     47 try:
     48     from charset_normalizer import __version__ as charset_normalizer_version

File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py:9
      1 """
      2 requests.exceptions
      3 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      4 
      5 This module contains the set of Requests' exceptions.
      6 """
      7 from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError
----> 9 from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
     12 class RequestException(IOError):
     13     """There was an ambiguous exception that occurred while handling your
     14     request.
     15     """

File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/compat.py:13
     11     import chardet
     12 except ImportError:
---> 13     import charset_normalizer as chardet
     15 import sys
     17 # -------
     18 # Pythons
     19 # -------
     20 
     21 # Syntax sugar.

File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/charset_normalizer/__init__.py:24
      2 """
      3 Charset-Normalizer
      4 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   (...)
     20 :license: MIT, see LICENSE for more details.
     21 """
     22 import logging
---> 24 from .api import from_bytes, from_fp, from_path
     25 from .legacy import detect
     26 from .models import CharsetMatch, CharsetMatches

File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/charset_normalizer/api.py:5
      2 from os import PathLike
      3 from typing import Any, BinaryIO, List, Optional, Set
----> 5 from .cd import (
      6     coherence_ratio,
      7     encoding_languages,
      8     mb_encoding_languages,
      9     merge_coherence_ratios,
     10 )
     11 from .constant import IANA_SUPPORTED, TOO_BIG_SEQUENCE, TOO_SMALL_SEQUENCE, TRACE
     12 from .md import mess_ratio

File ~/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/charset_normalizer/cd.py:8
      5 from typing import Counter as TypeCounter, Dict, List, Optional, Tuple
      7 from .assets import FREQUENCIES
----> 8 from .constant import KO_NAMES, LANGUAGE_SUPPORTED_COUNT, TOO_SMALL_SEQUENCE, ZH_NAMES
      9 from .md import is_suspiciously_successive_range
     10 from .models import CoherenceMatches

ImportError: cannot import name 'KO_NAMES' from 'charset_normalizer.constant' (/home/myname/miniconda3/envs/EMBI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/charset_normalizer/constant.py)
```

And this is related pkgs I was using:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuTLF.png)

I've tried updating charset_normalizer pkg, but encountered this question.

Comment: I've tried this methods and solved the problem. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775462/python-3-7-import-requests-returns-chardet-error) [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76180804/importerror-cannot-import-name-get-cpp-backtrace-from-torch-c/78158745#78158745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `chardet` module : `pip install chardet`

Comment: Thanks for ur help ~~  I did try this method and it works!